# Does django AppDirectoriesFinder looks in compressed files?

Tags: python, django

I have several third party django apps downloaded from pip as python eggs. Some of them have zip-safe flag set so they are compressed. I've noticed that django collectstatic command can't find static files from compressed eggs. Is there any posibility to make django taking staticfiles out of zipped eggs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Django does not look inside zipped eggs. But you can make your own ZipFileFinder based on Django's FileFinder, I think it will not be very much to code.

Comment: I just noticed that dajaxice app ships as compressed egg but still it manages to expose it's js files.